# How to add a worker/manager to a Docker Swarm cluster outside of the network?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want to add a additional worker/manager to my docker swarm cluster. However this additional worker/manager is not part of the network of the existing cluster.

I read that it is possible if

> Swarm Docker Agent can offer a socket accessible from outside (NAT-ed/PAT-ed)

What does that mean precisely and where is this documented